# Animate UIView out scaled behaves strangely

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, core-animation

I've had this problem before, but couldn't figure out what it is.

If I'm animating a view "standalone" in the Playground, this sort of thing looks fine, but now it just looks like in the provided GIF.

Animate it in look fine, but when I want to animate it out (scale) it just gets maxed-out size then disappears.

[image]

Here's the code that animates it:

```
self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
    self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
}, completion: {
    finished in
    if finished {
        self.resetStyle()
        self.circleView.hidden = true
        self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }
})

func resetStyle() {
    self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    self.circleView.backgroundColor = nil
    self.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Comment: what is `self.resetStyle()` doing?

Comment: I'll add it to the question

Comment: Have you tried to apply this animation to your view's layer instead of applying it directly to `UIView` ? And replace your affine transformation with 3D transformations?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: UIView!

@IBAction func leftAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.circleView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.001, 0.001, 1)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        self.circleView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    }
}

@IBAction func rightAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    circleView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        self.circleView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.001, 0.001, 1)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    circleView.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
    circleView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetMidY(circleView.bounds)
}
```

[image]